# architectural design with NSB

Tags: nservicebus

I recently stepped in a implementation of NServiceBus as a developer/analyst together with a new project manager. The project is past feasibility and design phase. Prior implementation work was done using NSB endpoints in a Pub/Sub setup.

Project Manager now changed the design so that he wants to organize all endpoints on a single server. By this he wants to mimic a broker system and even specified to have the publishers polling for XML files on a share. Messages will flow through the bus (on same server) and subscriber endpoints (again, same broker) will place XML files on a target system. He strongly believes that this way you decouple systems and sees great advantage in bordering the Bus responsibilities at the XML files.

I tried to build a case with these arguments

- decoupling sits between endpoints
- EAI logic should benefit from NSB fault-tolerant systems
- Central architecture creates single point of failure
- EAI logic outside NSB needs own monitoring and logging (not scalable)
- New applications will have XML import/export requirements

For building my case I referenced a lot of the excellent documentation. Problem is all of the documentation is very technical and the real innovation is read between the lines.

So my question is to help (counter)argument my case by sharing your thoughts and/or any good (human-readable) references.

Comment: Ask them how they will do an upgrade while messages or workflows are still in process.

Comment: they want to build a failover for the broker. This is probably how he wants to push upgrades.

Comment: To clarify, what if you want to upgrade the messages or workflows?  You'll have to drain the system or somehow bridge them to the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is being proposed sounds like a very archaic version of what Biztalk does very well and is made to do.

A few articles that include information about Biztalk vs. NSB (from the NSB website):
http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/861018-overview
http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/861257-nservicebus-and-biztalk

The cost of implementing Biztalk is pretty massive, with the required hardware (including failover) and software licensing (SQL Server and Biztalk itself).

As a general matter, though, your question is probably more suited to a discussion forum than the Q&A format of StackOverflow.  You might post it in the NSB group:

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/

Comment: Guess I just needed some community approval since I am on an island on this one. Tech group on yahoo was a good help. NSB is a great technology and am still excited about it. Just a pitty to see all its potential go to waste. [nsb tech group msg 17669](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/17669)